# Automatic cast to double in parameter

Tags: java, casting, floating-point, double, signature

Why does Java cast point numbers automatic to double? When I cast it, it works. But this is no beautiful way in my opinion.

My Methods could be change to double in signature. But when I import something I find no solution.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(0.1);
        run(1*0.1);
        run(1);
        importedClass.setPosition(0.1, 3.5); 
        //setPosition(float, float) not applicable for the arguments (double, double)
        run((float) 0.1);
        run((float) 1*0.1);
        run(1);
        importedClass.setPosition((float) 0.1, (float) 3.5); 
    }

    public static void run(float x) {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Throws Unresolved compilation problems:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method run(float) in the type Demo is not applicable for the arguments (double)
The method run(float) in the type Demo is not applicable for the arguments (double)

at test.Demo.main(Demo.java:6)
```

Comment: Because `0.1` is a double literal; an integer multiplied by a double is a double etc. If you want a float literal, use the `f` suffix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when a suffix 'f' or 'd' is not specified for a decimal number, java automatically defaults it to a double.

Therefore, 
**run(0.1);**

becomes:
**run(0.1d);**

Comment: Can I change this in a Java-Project?

Comment: You can try to create an overloaded method `run(double  x)`, downcast the value to float and call `run(float x)` from there, at a risk of losing information in down casting. Basically, `run(0.1)` would invoke the double method and then, this method, would invoke, the float method.

Comment: Although I would personally use the uppercase variant of the suffix, if just to be symmetric with the suffix for long `L`, which is preferred because `l` is confusing.

Answer (score 4):

As defined in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d

So instead of casting you can make it clear to the compiler that you are actually using a literal of type `float` by using a suffix:

```
run(0.1f);
```